# Selecting the contents of one column by searching the adjacent column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two different pandas data frame sets. One of them is a list of terms; these terms are strings:

```
df_1
apple
panda
lecture
sky
green
```

While the other one contains 2 columns, one of them a string that contains a title of a program, while the second one contains a list of tags for that program.

```
df_2
Program                           Tags      
Fruits of the World            [what,apple,green,banana,kiwi]
Animal in the Zoo              [panda,lion,eagle]
Lecture 1                      [panda,lecture,red]
The Old Man and the Sea        [book, blue, sea, lecture]
Sea Shanties                   [book,song,sea,dance]
```

---

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Program': {0: 'Fruits of the World',
  1: 'Animal in the Zoo',
  2: 'Lecture 1',
  3: 'The Old Man and the Sea',
  4: 'Sea Shanties'},
 'Tags': {0: ['what','apple','green','banana','kiwi'],
  1: ['panda','lion','eagle'],
  2: ['panda','lecture','red'],
  3: ['book', 'blue', 'sea', 'lecture'],
  4: ['book','song','sea','dance']}})
```

---

From this, I want to get a third data frame that contains the first column of df_1 and in it's second column contain the matching Programs from df_2. Ex:

```
df_3
Term               Program      
apple              Fruits of the World  
panda              Animal in the Zoo, Lecture 1
lecture            The Old Man and the Sea, Lecture 1
green              Fruits of the World
```

How could I go around doing that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where exactly did you fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `df.merge` with `df.groupby` and `df.groupby.agg`. Assuming your `df1` has just 1 column: (if not replace `df1.squeeze()` with `df1['your_col_name']`)

```
out = (df2.explode("Tags").merge(df1.squeeze().rename("Tags"))
 .groupby("Tags",sort=False)['Program'].agg(','.join).reset_index())
```

---

```
print(out)

      Tags                            Program
0    apple                Fruits of the World
1    green                Fruits of the World
2    panda        Animal in the Zoo,Lecture 1
3  lecture  Lecture 1,The Old Man and the Sea
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that say that there is no common term here.

     No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False

Comment: @Alokin Can you update the question with the exact column names you have? This should work if you can use the column names wisely

Comment: Thank you. I did manage to get it to work, I just had to separate the steps and change the type. So, it went like this:
df2_str  = df2_str.explode("Tags")    
df2_str = sf2_str['Tags'].apply(str)  
df2_str = df2_str.groupby(['Tags'])['Programs'].apply(' , '.join)  
df2_str = df2_str.to_frame().reset_index()  
full_results = df1.join(df2_str.set_index('Term'), on='Term')

Comment: @Alokin Glad you figured it. :)